# Перебор тегов XML (XML::Simple)

Tags: xml, perl

Допустим, есть XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pets>
    <cat>
        <name>Барсик</name>
        <age>2</age>
    </cat>
    <cat>
        <name>Васька</name>
        <age>3</age>
    </cat>
</pets>
```

Мы получаем его через XML::Simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use XML::Simple;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
$xml = XML::Simple->new();
$list = $xml->XMLin('pets.xml');
```

Как, перебрав в цикле все теги cat и проверяя у каждого age, вывести имя кота, которому 3 года?

Comment: Смотреть в сторону использования xpath, думаю и перл умеет его использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужны ещё несколько строк

```
for my $cat ( keys $list->{cat} ) {
    if ($list->{cat}->{$cat}->{age} == 3) {
        print "$cat\n";
    }
}
```